# php mysql sum and sort by

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sum

mysql table called workout has the following layout:

```
exercise   |weight|sets|reps|action  | wn
----------------------------------------------
deadlift   |  80  |  6 |  1 | pull   | 32
bb press   |  40  |  3 |  5 | push   | 32
bb rows    |  20  |  2 |  5 | pull   | 31
blahblah   |  blah|  3 |  5 | push   | 31 
blahblah   |  blah|  3 |  5 | squat  | 31
blahblah   |  blah|  3 |  5 | push   | 30
blahblah   |  blah|  3 |  5 | hinge  | 30
blahblah   |  blah|  3 |  5 | carry  | 29
```

i want to sort the results as sum sets*reps for each action, then sort results by wn and display in a table using php.

so i would have a row for each wn and totals of each action like:

```
wn | push | pull | squat | hinge | carry 
----------------------------------------
32 | 80   | 120  |  90   | 180   | 40
31 | 65   | 60   |  80   | 150   | 34
30                          
29
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem right, you could do something like that :

```
// $rows are your MySQL fetch_assoc rows
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if(!isset ($wn_array[$row['wn']][$row['action']]) 
        $wn_array[$row['wn']][$row['action']] = ($row['sets'] * $row['reps']);
    else
        $wn_array[$row['wn']][$row['action']] += ($row['sets'] * $row['reps']); 
}
```

You'll get a $wn_array somehow corresponding to what you're looking for, whish should be quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If all actions are known upfront you can do *conditional `SUM`*

```sql
SELECT wn,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'push'  THEN sets * reps END) push,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'pull'  THEN sets * reps END) pull,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'squat' THEN sets * reps END) squat,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'hinge' THEN sets * reps END) hinge,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'carry' THEN sets * reps END) carry
  FROM workout
 GROUP BY wn DESC
```

Sample output:

```
| WN |   PUSH |   PULL |  SQUAT |  HINGE |  CARRY |
---------------------------------------------------
| 32 |     15 |      6 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 31 |     15 |     10 |     15 | (null) | (null) |
| 30 |     15 | (null) | (null) |     15 | (null) |
| 29 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     15 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/399cd9/3)** demo

Comment: @chocman Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?